# onClick javascript function executes only once per page load

Tags: javascript, html

so I made 2 buttons, which looks like this:

```
<input id="buttonLED1_green" type="button" value="green LED" onClick="writeLED(1,0)">
<input id="buttonLED1_red" type="button" value="red LED" onClick="writeLED(1,1)">
```

And the function that is being executed onCLick:

```
function writeLED(id, color) {
    try {
        SetDataAnalog( id+400,  color, 1,true);
        document.write("hi");
    } catch (e) {

    }
}
```

and this one sends an xmlHTTP request to change an analog datapoint on my other device that stores numbers on addresses.

```
var xmlHttp = new Array(2); // Index 0 fĂĽrs Lesen, Index 1 fĂĽrs Schreiben
var ddcURL = "http://192.168.1.60/";
function SetDataAnalog(addr, wert, endeAdddr, isFullQualified) {
    endeAdddr = parseInt(endeAdddr);
    var cmd;
    if (isFullQualified) {
        cmd = ddcURL + "SetADP:" + addr + ":" + wert;
    } else {
        cmd = ddcURL + "SetADP:" + addr + ":" + wert;
    }
    try{
        if (xmlHttp[1]){
            xmlHttp[1].open('GET', cmd, true);
            xmlHttp[1].send(null);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        alert('error');
    }
}
```

The problem is, the first time I click any of the buttons, they work and the 0 or the 1 is being set on the analog adress 401, but when I click it a second time, all the functions also get executed, but the data is becouse of any reason not written on the 401 adress. Becouse of some reason it works again once when I close my browser and reopen the page.

Comment: Is it possible the request is being cached?

Comment: I have another function like this which, when you press the button, it gets the value from the input and puts it in a variable, but then does the same as here, where there is only a button, without a text input, but the other one works great, although both send the exact same request (but the value of course)

Comment: If it is, as @JamesMontagne suggests, being cached, you could append a time stamp to your query string (as long as your device doesn't choke on it) that will make each request unique and avoid caching.

Comment: If the value in the textbox changes each time, this would prevent caching.  Try putting the same value in the text box multiple times and see if it caches.